# Placing numeric value into an Array range

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has numeric values stored. like this:

```
$ranges = array(1=> '33', 2=> '66', 3=> '99');
```

i have a variable called `$result` that gives me a dynamic value between 0-100.

for example:

- If `$result` is equal to or greater than 33 AND less than 66, then the returned key should be 1
- If `$result` is equal to or greater than 66 AND less than 99, then the returned key should be 2
- If `$result` is equal to or greater than 99, then the returned key should be 3

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Use if else elseif it's the best practice

Comment: What part of writing the logic are you having difficulty with?

Comment: i'm finding it difficult to apply the if else rule to search an array value and return the key

Comment: I have the following which works, but only works when the numbers match 100% 

$ranges = array(1=> '33', 2=> '66', 3=> '99');

$key = "66";

if(false !== ($index = array_search($key,$ranges)))
{
    echo $index; //5
}

Comment: What is your reasoning behind organizing this data in an array like this? What happens when the result is less than 33?

Comment: I have a percentage band, which the returned $result needs to fall into, if its less than the first number then the return needs to be empty. The 33, 66, and 99, can also change, so it can be 20, 40, 80, 100

Answer (score 1):

For your conditions

1. When 33 <= result < 66 then getRangeIndex = 1
2. When 66 <= result < 99 then getRangeIndex = 2
3. When 99 <= result then getRangeIndex = 3

The function may be like this:

```
function getRangeIndex( $i ) {

    $ranges = array(1=> '33', 2=> '66', 3=> '99');
    $prevValue = 0;
    $prevKey = null;
    foreach( $ranges as $currKey=>$currValue ) {
        if( $prevValue <= $i && $i < $currValue ) {
            return $prevKey;
        }
        $prevValue = $currValue;
        $prevKey = $currKey;
    }
    return $currKey;
}
```

Simple loop for test function:

```
for( $result = 0 ; $result <= 100 ; $result++ ) {
    echo "$result - " . getRangeIndex( $result ) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How you approach this is partially dependent on how dynamic you want the conditional logic to be. If you're simply checking against this array of values, it's trivial to set up a sequence of several `if` and `else if` statements.

However, if you want this to be a bit more dynamic, you should start by rearranging your inputs a bit. When you organize your array like you've done, you're confusing different limit values. 33 is an upper exclusive limit for the `0` range, 66 is an upper exclusive limit for the `1` range, 99 is an upper exclusive limit for the `2` range, and 100 is an upper *inclusive* limit for the `3` range.

A naive solution to this would be to simply shift your 33, 66, and 99 values down by one and iterate over the list performing a `<=` check for that range. This means 32 would return `0` and 33 would return `1`, but 32.5 would also return `1`. So absent any other information, this will get you what you need:

```
$ranges = array(0 => 33, 1 => 66, 2 => 99, 3 => 101);

foreach ($ranges as $key => $value)
{
    if ($result < $value)
    {
        $best = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges are always in order you won't need to check the lower limit, so something like this would work:

```
$resndx= 0;
foreach($ranges as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value > $result) {
        break;
    }
    $resndx= $key;
}

echo "Result $result is in $resndx";
```